# Change font of one part of the element of string array for Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-typeface

I am trying to change the font for only one part of the string of the string array but it can't work. I am trying to implement something like this below:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/greek.ttf");

SpannableStringBuilder SS1 = new SpannableStringBuilder("ws=");
SS1.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

arraySpinner = new String[] {"s ", "ms", SS1.toString()};
s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

So that `"ws="` would have `w` converted to corresponding greek font symbol, and `s=` would stay in the default font.

If I try to insert `SS1.toString()` in `arraySpinner` it seems to lose all the Typeface characteristics when it is set `.toString()`.
Is there an another way?

Comment: `tiString` returns a String, not a `SpannableString`. You will have to change ArrayAdapter<String> to ArrayAdapter<SpannableString>, and maybe also need to override the binding, as by default toString() is called by adapter.

Comment: You were right at pointing me to this way. I used 'ArrayAdapter<SpannableStringBuilder>'  and it worked.